# filter a list based on values in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
list2 = [1,0,1,0]
```

Given two lists like the above, I would like to obtain a third list whose values are `['a','c']`

In other words, I'd like the target list to be the values from `list1` where the corresponding element in `list2` is `1`.

Comment: Try `[i for i, j in zip(list1, list2) if j == 1]`?

Answer (score 1):

Use enumerate function on second list to include index, which can be used for the first list.

```
[list1[i] for i, item in enumerate(list2) if item]
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments:

`[i for i, j in zip(list1, list2) if j]` would work.

Alternatively, if you were looking for something not so advanced:

```
list3 = []

for i in range(len(list1)):
    if list2[i] == 1:
        list3.append(list1[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Generators can be nice if you have very long lists:

```
def filterfunc(a, b, keyvalue=1):
    return (x for i, x in enumerate(a) if b[i] == keyvalue)
```

To get the whole sequence:

```
list(filterfunc(a, b))
```